# KnockoutJS Grid to add items

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I currently have a form that will let the users to add item to the submission, since I am very new to KnockoutJS I just made this form to accept the one Product for the submission

```
<script type="text/html" id="page4-template">
<h4>Strain Information : </h4>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="firstCol">Stock number : </td>
        <td><span id="SummaryP1_StockNum" data-bind="text: stockNumber"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="firstCol">Product Needed : </td>
        <td>
            <span id="SummaryP1_pdtNeeded" data-bind="text: pdtNeeded"></span>
            <span data-bind="visible: pdtNeeded() == 'Other'">
                <span id="SummaryP1_pdtNeededPleaseExplain" data-bind="text: pdtNeededPleaseExplain"></span>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="firstCol">Requested Ship Date : </td>
        <td><span id="SummaryP1_RequestedShipDate" data-bind="text: requestedShipDate"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="firstCol">Aditional Information : </td>
        <td><span id="SummaryP1_AdditionalInformation" data-bind="text: additionalInformation"></span></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<hr>
</script>
```

If I need to make this form to allow users to add more item to the submission dynamically, what should I be using here, I am little confused as thee are dynamic bootstrapping, Overservable Array and all. Can anyone please suggest what could I do to simple to allow users to dynamically add item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest three steps:

The first step would be collect into one object all those observable properties which you bind to the table's elements:

```
createRowItem = function(data) {
    return {
        additionalInformation = ko.observable(data.additionalInformation),
        pdtNeeded = ko.observable(data.pdtNeeded),
        pdtNeededPleaseExplain = ko.obsevable(data.pdtNeededPleaseExplain),
        requestedShipDate = ko.observable(data.requestedShipDate),
        stockNumber = ko.observable(data.stockNumber),
    }
};
```

You would obtain an instance of a new `rowItem`...

```
var newRowItem = createRowItem(data);
```

The second step is to create an `observableArray` ([documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)) in your existing view-model:

```
self.rowItems = ko.observableArray([]);
```

To populate that array with your collection of `rowItem` instances you *could* call `self.rowItems.push(newRowItem)` ([documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#pop-push-shift-unshift-reverse-sort-splice)) but it's more efficient to obtain a reference to the inner array (*i.e.*, the primitive array which the observableArray is watching), add the new instance to that, then tell the observableArray that its data has been updated. [The reason for this efficiency has to do with the way Knockout works internally, and tracks mutations.]

My suggestion would be to do this inside a public function on your view-model:

```
self.addRowItem = function(newRowItem) {
    var arr = ko.unwrap(self.rowItems);  // obtain the underlying array
    arr.push(newRowItem);  // add the new object to the underlying array
    self.rowItems.valueHasMutated();  // tell Knockout that the underlying array has been modified
};
```

The final step is to wrap your `<tr>` elements in a `foreach` binding ([documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)):

```
<script type="text/html" id="page4-template">
<h4>Strain Information : </h4>
<table data-bind="foreach: rowItems">
    <tr>
        <td class="firstCol">Stock number : </td>
        <td><span id="SummaryP1_StockNum" data-bind="text: stockNumber"></span></td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Comment: I tried exactly as you suggested but I am getting error and not able to get it working.. Added another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67310258/dynamically-repeat-the-table-using-the-observablearray can you please help me what I am missing here

Comment: Can you pleas help when you have a min, I am kind of stuck with that error

Comment: I think I see the problem in my solution which has caused your problem. I was about to post an answer to your other question but you seek to have removed it. Just in case, I've updated my answer - check out the first code block containing `createRowItem`.

Comment: @awj As you suggested I cahnged the input parameter to the Array but I am running in to issues again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67353373/ajax-call-that-pass-knockoutjs-observable-array-to-the-http-post-controller-meth  can you please help me with what I am missing here

Answer (score 1):

You will indeed want to use an `observableArray` to store multiple items. Then you loop through this array with the `foreach` binding and you add a method on your viewmodel to push new items to this array.

Something like this:

```
vm.row = ko.observableArray();

vm.addRow = function () {
    vm.row.push({
        stockNumber: ko.observable(1),
        pdtNeeded: ko.observable('Other'),
        pdtNeededPleaseExplain: ko.observable('Hello'),
        requestedShipDate: ko.observable(),
        additionalInformation: ko.observable()
    })
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/2q8tbp5n/

For good measure, I also added an example of how you could remove the rows.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did follow as you explained here and I am not able to get it working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67310028/unable-to-store-multiple-items-through-the-observable-array Can you please help me know what I am missing